# Rails & Devise: how to post form after devise login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that all users can fill out (both logged in and logged out users).

For logged in users, when they submit the form, they go to the confirmation page just fine.

**For logged out users, when they post the form, I want them to go to the devise login page and then directly to the confirmation page.**

Is that possible?

I know a lazy way is to not show the form until the user logs in, but this is a flow is a requirement (showing the form to all users regardless if they're logged in or not).

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you have to do some tweaks in device login method. If you can show your sample code, it will be helpful to answer.

Comment: you can take help of `session`, for example when a logged out user submits a form I will store `path of confirmation page` in the session. After that I will check if I have that particular path in session then I will redirect to that particular path. For checking this I will need to override `after_sign_in_path_for` method of `Devise gem`.

Comment: Why don't you try wicked? https://github.com/schneems/wicked railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked